# How to add number of days to a date field in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a date field in a table named product. I need to add some days to this field how to d this. I am new to PostgreSQL.

I tried this:

```
select manufacture_dt + weeks*7 from product;
```

It is giving me the error

```
operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone + integer.
Hint no operator matches the given name and argument types .you might need to add  explicit type cast
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming 'weeks' is a column containing number of days in integer in that table 'product',
If you want to multiply 'weeks' columns value with the 'manufacture_dt' column you can try below query :-

```
select
       manufacture_dt + interval '7 day' * weeks as new_date
from product
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 4):

There is no `+` operator for `timestamp` and `integer`, but there is one for `timestamp` and `interval`. Moreover, `interval`s can be multiplied with numbers.

So you could write:

```
SELECT manufacture_dt + weeks * INTERVAL '7 days'
FROM product;
```

The syntax `DATATYPE 'somevalue'` is SQL syntax for a constant (literal) of a certain data type.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `date` column, you have a `timestamp` column.

You can only add an `interval` to a `timestamp` value

If `weeks` is another column in your table, you can use `make_interval` to generated the interval

```
select manufacture_dt + make_interval(weeks => weeks::int)
from product;
```